# Python/Twisted - Sending to a specific socket object?

Tags: python, sockets, twisted, multiprocess

I have a "manager" process on a node, and several worker processes. The manager is the actual server who holds all of the connections to the clients. The manager accepts all incoming packets and puts them into a queue, and then the worker processes pull the packets out of the queue, process them, and generate a result. They send the result back to the manager (by putting them into another queue which is read by the manager), but here is where I get stuck: how do I send the result to a specific socket? When dealing with the processing of the packets on a single process, it's easy, because when you receive a packet you can reply to it by just grabbing the "transport" object in-context. But how would I do this with the method I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to keep a reference to the transport (or protocol) along with the bytes the just came in on that protocol in your 'event' object.  That way responses that came in on a connection go out on the same connection.

If things don't need to be processed serially perhaps you should think about setting up functors that can handle the data in parallel to remove the need for queueing.  Just keep in mind that you will need to protect critical sections of your code.

Edit:
Judging from your other question about evaluating your server design it would seem that processing in parallel may not be possible for your situation, so my first suggestion stands.